# What is the recommended Ruby editor under windows?

Tags: ruby

What is the recommended Ruby editor under Windows? Should has syntax highlight, debug etc.

Comment: You're going to use a separate editor for JavaScript? I'm getting happier with Sublime Text 2 and use IntelliJ for most everything else. This isn't a programming question, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) from Jetbrains (creators of IntelliJ IDEA, Resharper and more). It has all the features you specified and a lot more, like location of code in the gems connected to your project, smart refactorings etc.

Answer (score 1):

> **Basic Editor:**

Mac:
    http://macromates.com/ (visual, wysiwyg),  Currently €39 ≈ $52
    vim (techy, unixy).  Free

Windows:
    [intype](http://inotai.com/intype/) (like textmate but for Windows), Currently Free.
    notepad,  Free.
    metapad (basic), Free.

Linux:
    vim, gedit, Free.

**My Choice: vi/vim**

> **IDE's** - that work on all three platform (Mac/Win/*nix):

[Aptana Eclipse](http://aptana.com/), Free.
  [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), Free.
  [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), $69.

Personally for an IDE I used Eclipse, then netBeans (both free) then rubyMine (paid, < $100)  in each case I found that the product I moved to had more features.  rubyMine ic clearly the most comprehensive with the most tools.
Make sure you have plenty of pc power as rubyMine needs a fair amount of memory, fast processors, etc. to work well.

**My Choice: rubyMine**

Final Note: [An IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is defined in Wikipedia as a product that is:

- a source code editor
- a compiler and/or an interpreter
- build automation tools
- a debugger

Comment: How is vim a "basic" editor? ;)

Comment: Your argument makes vim a simple IDE, it doesn't make it a simple editor. That was my point.

Comment: We can definitely agree that this discussion is out of scope :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.e-texteditor.com/ - lightweight and simple, haven't used it since I moved to Mac (don't know if it's still alive), but it's close to TextMate and allows to use TextMate bundles.